# Button on far right despite only being in 2nd (1) column

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import random
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

FirstPageFrame = Frame(root)  # CREATES FIRST PAGE FRAME
FirstPageFrame.pack()  # CREATES FIRST PAGE FRAME


RolltheDiceTitle = Label(FirstPageFrame, text="Roll the Dice")
RolltheDiceTitle.config(font=("Courier", 30))
RolltheDiceTitle.grid()

LoginRegisterWelcomeMessage = Label(FirstPageFrame, text="Welcome to the Roll the Dice Game.")
LoginRegisterWelcomeMessage.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

DiceImage = PhotoImage(file="dice.png")
DiceImageLabel = Label(FirstPageFrame, image=DiceImage)
DiceImageLabel.grid()

registerButton = Button(FirstPageFrame, text="Register", fg="orange")  # CREATES REGISTER BUTTON
registerButton.grid(row=4, padx=10, pady=10)
loginButton = Button(FirstPageFrame, text="Login", fg="Green")  # CREATES LOGIN BUTTON
loginButton.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


root.mainloop()  # Continues tkinter window loop so program does not close
```

I'm trying to have both the register and login buttons in the middle of the window (where register button is located) but side by side, not stacked.

Apologies for any incorrect formatting with this question or any easy fixes with the code. I'm super new to Tkinter and trying to figure stuff out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put the Login button in column 1 all the other widgets are in column 0, so the Login button will be displayed on the far right.

One solution is to create a contaner frame for the buttons which can be placed in the center of column 0, and then place the buttons in culmns in that frame.

I have stated row and colun explicitly for all widgets which makes it easier to follow, and also assigned a bg color to the buttonFrame so you can see where it goes.

```
import random
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

FirstPageFrame = Frame(root)  # CREATES FIRST PAGE FRAME
FirstPageFrame.pack()  # CREATES FIRST PAGE FRAME

RolltheDiceTitle = Label(FirstPageFrame, text="Roll the Dice")
RolltheDiceTitle.config(font=("Courier", 30))
RolltheDiceTitle.grid(row=0, column=0)

LoginRegisterWelcomeMessage = Label(FirstPageFrame, text="Welcome to the Roll the Dice Game.")
LoginRegisterWelcomeMessage.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

DiceImage = PhotoImage(file="dice.png")
DiceImageLabel = Label(FirstPageFrame, image=DiceImage)
DiceImageLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

# Here is the container frame for the buttons. 
buttonFrame = Frame(FirstPageFrame, bg='tan') # bg color to indicate 
buttonFrame.grid(row=3)                       # position and extent of frame

registerButton = Button(buttonFrame, text="Register", fg="orange")  # CREATES REGISTER BUTTON
registerButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
loginButton = Button(buttonFrame, text="Login", fg="Green")  # CREATES LOGIN BUTTON
loginButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()  # Continues tkinter window loop so program does not close
```